# stretch linearGradient paint in android

Tags: android, linear-gradients

I have this gradient:

```
gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 150, Color.WHITE, Color.GRAY, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
```

Right now it has a height of a 150 but I would like this hight to be the same as the canvas or the parent view. I will use the gradient inside a onDraw(Canvas) so I can't use the new statement. Is it possible to do without the new statement?

BR
FireFly3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use it in the onMeasure method , or if you insist on putting it in the onDraw method , set it only once by using a field (and check if it's null).

Comment: That will give me the same problem as before. It isn't good to create new entities in layout or draw meathods :(

Comment: if you only set it once, then it will be wrong as the dimensions change. You need to set it any time the dimensions change

Comment: @GregEnnis If you are talking about onMeasure, this doesn't get called a lot. If you talk about onDraw, you should do everything you can to avoid re-creating new objects.

Comment: It doesnt get called a lot... unless it does

Comment: @GregEnnis Sure. It all depends on what you want to do.